# Cryptocurrency Transfer programmatically

Tags: currency, ethereum, bitcoin, transfer

I need to transfer x amount of cryptocurrencies (like bitcoin, ethereum, kbc) programmatically from one wallet to another. Then, I need to verify if the sender sent the money to the address of the recipient's wallet.

Is there any library for doing that? Is there any documented api on any web services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for services like Shapeshift or alternatives.

There are a bunch over https://news.bitcoin.com/four-alternatives-to-shapeshift/.
For some of them, you'll have to do some KYC.

If what you wanted to achieve is only to send a transaction to move funds within the same blockchain, I would suggest using APIs to push&monitor transactions to do so.

ETH: https://infura.io/docs
BTC: https://www.blockchain.com/api

Comment: Thanks, but i wonder if that api works if i have a store like web site and i want to the user make a payment to my store, and then the store check/verify the payment programmatically ?

Comment: Usually, what you do is this:
 1. You generate a one time address

 2. You show the address and the amount for a specified amount of time

 3. You monitor (through the use of API or a blockchain client)(programmatically) the specified address

 4. Inform the user whether the time for payment has expired or payment receive

Comment: Thank you. A little scared, it's my first time with cryptocurrencies. Do you have an example in any language?